# How to turn off the water valve to the sprinkler

Tags: water, leak, sprinkler-system

[image]

I believe one of our sprinkler units is leaking…I have turned off the sprinkler system however I want to turn the water off to the sprinkler manual valve . Would I do it from the back flow I assume…but I’m not sure which one to turn it off

Comment: what manual valve

Comment: Sorry meant to add a picture

Comment: the left valve would be your water main inlet. The right one is water to the sprinklers. somewhere there is the controller/timer (with wires)

Comment: Could you post a clearer picture with in-focus detail of the valve area? Which of the 2 white pipes going into the ground goes to the sprinklers, and which goes back upstream to your water supply? Is the big round green thing the "sprinkler manual valve"?

Comment: Why do you need to turn off the water supply to fix a sprinkler head?  Just turn the computer from "Run" to "Off" while you're working.  Either of the valves in your picture will stop water flow too, and there might be another main valve somewhere else.  Look near the meter.